# Recommendations (and Differences) between different Ruby on Rails Production Web Servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, passenger, fastcgi, mongrel

Very soon I plan on deploying my first Ruby on Rails application to a production environment and I've even picked a webhost with all the managed server and Capistrano goodness you'd expect from a RoR provider.

The provider allows for Mongrel, Thin, Passenger & FastCGI web servers, which seems very flexible, but I honestly don't know the differences between them.  I have looked into them some, but it all gets a bit much when they start talking about features and maximum simultaneous requests - and that this data seems to vary depending on who's publishing it.

I have looked at Passenger (on the surface) - which does seem very appealing to me - but I was under the impression that Passenger wasn't the actual webserver, and instead was more like a layer on top of Apache or nginx and managed spawned instances of the application (like a Mongrel cluster).

Can anyone please set me straight with the differences in layman's terms so as I can choose wisely (because anyone who's seen *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* knows what happens if you choose poorly).

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://tenmiles.com/blog/2010/08/apache-passenger-and-other-server-alternatives-rails/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Short answer**

Go with Apache/Nginx + Passenger. Passenger [is fast](http://www.modrails.com/documentation.html), reliable, easy to configure and deploy. Passenger has been adopted by a large number of big Rails applications, including [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/).

[image]
<sub>(source: [modrails.com](http://www.modrails.com/images/passenger_mongrel_thin_benchmark.png))</sub>

**The long answer**

Forget about CGI and FastCGI. In the beginning there were no other alternatives so the only way to run Rails was using CGI or the faster browser FastCGI. Nowadays almost nobody runs Rails under CGI. The latest Rails versions no longer provides .cgi and .fcgi runners.

Mongrel has been a largely adopted solution, the best replacement for CGI and FCGI. Many sites still use Mongrel and Mongrel cluster, however Mongrel project is almost dead and many projects already moved to other solutions (mostly Passenger).
Also, a Mongrel based architecture is quite hard to configure because it needs a frontend proxy (thin, ngnix) and a backend architecture composed of multiple Mongrel instances.

Passenger has been gaining widespread attention since it was released. Many projects switched from Mongrel to Passenger for many reasons, including (but not limited to) easy deployment, maintainability and performance. Additionally, Passenger is now available for both Apache and Ngnix.

The simplest way to use Passenger is the Apache + Passenger configuration. One Apache installation and multiple Passenger processes.

If you need better performance and scalability, you can use Ngnix as a frontend proxy and forward all Rails requests to multiple backend servers, each one composed of Apache + Passenger.
I'm not going into the technical details here, this solution is intended to be used by Rails projects with an high level of traffic.

Even more complex solutions include a combination of different levels including http proxies and servers. You can have an idea of what I'm talking about reading some internal details from [GitHub](http://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) and [Heroku](http://heroku.com/how/architecture).

Right now, Passenger is the best answer for most Rails projects.

Answer (score 9):

Mongrel and Thin are single ruby process servers that you would run multiple of as a cluster behind some type of proxy (like Apache or Nginx).  The proxy would manage which instance of Mongrel or Thin services the requests.

Passenger creates an interface between Apache or Nginx that creates an application spawning process and then forks out processes to server up incoming requests as they come in.  There are a lot of configuration options for how long those processes live, how many there can be, and how many requests they will serve before they die.  This is by far the most common way to scale up and handle a high traffic application, but it is not without drawbacks.  This can only be done on a *nix operating system (linux, mac os x, etc).  Also, these processes spin up on demand, so if no one accesses your site for a while, they processes die and the next request has the delay of it starting back up again.  With Mongrel and Thin, the process is always running.  Sometimes though, your processes being new and fresh can be a good thing for memory usage etc.

If it is going to be a relatively low traffic site, Mongrel or Thin provides a simple, easy to manage way to deploy the application.  For higher traffic sites where you need the smart queuing and process management of something like Passenger, it is a very good solution.

As for fastcgi, you probably want to use that as a last option.

Answer (score 1):

I use Passenger + nginx. It works really, really well.

Answer (score 1):

To get some instant performance boast with passenger, I recommend using ruby enterprise edition.