# which webserver is better for production for RoR hosting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, hosting

Which webserver is better for production for RoR hosting?

for example: mongrel vs apache2?

can mongrel does something that apache2 can not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendations (and Differences) between different Ruby on Rails Production Web Servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728978/recommendations-and-differences-between-different-ruby-on-rails-production-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongrel is an application server, while Apache 2 is a web server. They aren't competing with each other, but working together.

Having said that, you should forget about mongrel and go take a look at [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/index.html), which is an application server that will work with either Apache or Nginx (another web server).